# Multiple source CASCADE DELETE behavior

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, delete

I'm having trouble understanding Postgres's `CASCADE` `DELETE` [behavior](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-constraints.html).

If `table_A` `REFERENCES` `table_B`, and the column referenced could have multiple instances of the same value, will the `table_A` row be `DELETE`d even if there are still valid references upon a `table_B` `DELETE`?

If so, how can `table_A` only be `DELETE`d by `CASCADE` when there are no valid references left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must be misunderstanding `CASCADE` foreign keys, and/or the rules around foreign keys in general.

A foreign key can only refer to a table with a unique constraint or primary key. So in your example, you *cannot create a foreign key referencing `table_b`* if there can be multiple instances of a value in the referenced column.

When you `DELETE FROM ...` a table, and another table has an `ON DELETE CASCADE` foreign key reference to it, *all* referencing rows are deleted from the other table.

The column *referenced* cannot have multiple instances of the value, because you cannot create a foreign key to a column that is not `unique`.

The *referring* column of the table with the constraint  may have multiple values that refer to the column in the *referenced* table. If so, when the referenced value is removed, all these are deleted, as you would expect in a `CASCADE`.

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE table_b (id integer);
CREATE TABLE
regress=> INSERT INTO table_b (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (1);
INSERT 0 4
```

Can't create the foreign key, no unique constraint or PK:

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE table_a (b_id integer REFERENCES table_b(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "table_b"
```

Can't add a PK or unique constraint, has duplicates:

```
regress=> ALTER TABLE table_b ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ERROR:  could not create unique index "table_b_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is duplicated.
```

Comment: Thank you!  lol, yes, I was getting lost in my own spaghetti, and being a noob doesn't help either.